# Order of matches in syn-cluster

Tags: syntax-highlighting

For regular match groups, the last defined group will be the first to match.
When using match groups added to a cluster, I can't determine what the match order is. For example:

```
syn match allgroupcol3 "\%3c.\{10}" contained   " match 10 chars in col 3-12
syn match klgroupcol3 "\%3c\s*kl\zs.\{10}" contained   " match 10 chars in col 3-12, must start with 'kl'

syn cluster colCluster add=allgroupcol3
syn cluster colCluster add=klgroupcol3
```

`allgroupcol3` always matches, even if something in cols 3-12 starts with 'kl'.

What is the order of matches inside a cluster?